# How to parse CSV files in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, import-from-excel

I want to stock some fields in MySQL coming from Excel but I'm not arrived to cut the lines from Excel in PHP

example:

```
123,15,0,01/01/2000,456462ABCD,,,
```

any help please ?

Comment: What do you mean with *cut*, separate them? -> `explode()` ?!

Comment: Are you asking how to parse CSV files in PHP?

Comment: yes i want to parse CSV files in PHP

Answer (score 0):

Just use the function for parsing a CSV file

http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php

```
$row = 1;
if (($handle = fopen("test.csv", "r")) !== FALSE) {
  while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
   $num = count($data);
  echo "<p> $num fields in line $row: <br /></p>\n";
  $row++;
  for ($c=0; $c < $num; $c++) {
    echo $data[$c] . "<br />\n";
  }
 }
  fclose($handle);
}
```